# How to get Capybara to check a checkbox by its label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Capybara is not finding my checkbox's label, and I know I'm referencing it correctly by it's label.  What am I doing wrong, or is this a bug in Capybara?

According to [http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions:check](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3acheck), "The check box can be found via name, id or label text."

Here's the section of my request spec I ran:

```
describe "with valid information" do   

it_should_behave_like "all item pages"

before { valid_create_item }

it "should create an item" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(Item, :count).by(1)
end

describe "after saving the item" do
    before { click_button submit }

    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Items") }
    it { should have_title("Items") }
    it { should have_success_message }
end      

describe "and options selected" do

    before do
        puts page.html
        check('Option 1')
        click_button "Save changes"
    end

    it { should have_title("Items") }
    it { should have_success_message }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    specify { expect(item.reload.options.find_by_name("Option 1")).to eq true }
end
```

And here's a gist of the resulting test, including the html generated for the page:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11270055

According to the test results, Capybara couldn't find the checkbox labelled "Option 1", when it's clearly in the generated html.

As a sidenote, I've also noticed I can fill in a form by it's label with Capybara *only* when I let the rails FormHelper display a field's default label text.

For example: The FormHelper label text for a field called "email_address" appears as "Email address", and `fill_in "Email address", with: "blahblah@blah.com"` works.  If I don't use the FormHelper to generate the label, and instead make the label "Email", `fill_in "Email", with: "blahblah@blah.com"` doesn't work, because Capybara can't find the field labeled "Email".  It seems this behavior is consistent with all form elements (or at least with text fields and checkboxes -- the only ones I've tested so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html for Option 1 looks like:

```
<label class="control-label" for="__Option:0x000001061be660_">Option 1</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input id="options_" name="options[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</div>
```

The problem is that the label and checkbox are not properly associated with each other:

- The label has a `for` attribute of "__Option:0x000001061be660_"
- The checkbox has an `id` attribute of "options_"

As a result, Capybara finds the label "Option 1", but not one that is associated to a checkbox.

The page needs to be updated so that the label `for` attribute and checkbox `id` attribute match. For example:

```
<label class="control-label" for="__Option:0x000001061be660_">Option 1</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input id="__Option:0x000001061be660_" name="options[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: So the statement "The check box can be found via name, id or label text" in the Capybara documentation is not entirely true.  Now that I've got the label's `for` attribute matching the checkbox's `id`, `check 'Option 1'` works as expected.  Thanks @JustinKo

Answer (score 3):

You should use `allow_label_click: true` option

for checkboxes:

```
choose("mention_sentiment_positive", allow_label_click: true)
```

for radios

```
choose("mention_sentiment_positive", allow_label_click: true)
```

Don't know if this option was available in your days :D

Comment: Obviously for checkboxes the method should be `check(...` but except that good answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can also make Capybara find the checkbox by using [`check(\[locator\], options)` method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3Acheck) by passing the value of the checkbox as an option.

The code is `page.check(name, option: value)`, where name is the name of the checkbox and value - its value.

This also should work for `id` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it directly based off of the input instead?

```
<div class="control-group offset2"> 
<label class="control-label" for="__Option:0x000001061be660_">Option 1</label>
<div class="controls">
<input id="options_" name="options[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
/div>
</div>
```

If you ever want to debug further, you could add a binding.pry before it checks it, and then just run a few capybara node checking commands to see if it can actually detect the element or not.

If you don't want to use pry, you could just do a

```
puts all('.control-label', text: 'Option 1').size
```

and if it returns 1, then it's detected, and thus you could just do a

```
find('.control-label', text: 'Option 1').set(true)
```

The check method for Capybara is this:

```
File 'lib/capybara/node/actions.rb', line 78
def check(locator, options={})
  find(:checkbox, locator, options).set(true)
end
```

If it doesn't work to do it based off the label like that, you could try doing it based off of the input.

Comment: I'm less interested in a different technique than I am in figuring out if Capybara should be finding the checkbox the way I've written the test.  "puts all('.control-label', text: 'Option 1').size" returned 2, which is weird, since there's only one in the generated html, and if two are found, Capybara2 is supposed to return an Ambiguous error, AFAIK.

Comment: Update:  I just tried "find('.control-label', text: 'Option 1').set(true)", which did return an Ambiguous match error.  The html generated in the gist linked in my question clearly shows only one instance of a label 'Option 1', so I don't understand why Capybara is detecting two.

Comment: Hey sorry just saw this. Yes I realize that you were asking specifically for the label, I'm pretty sure Justin answered that for you. It may be that it's detecting Option 1 and Option 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `allow_label_click`

```rb
check("marketing", allow_label_click: true)
```